# Google Cloud Endpoints Upload Image as BytesField - Error 400 Invalid bytes value

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to create an endpoint method to upload an image. I'm sending the image as base64. My method looks like this:

```
@endpoints.method(endpoints.ResourceContainer(file=messages.BytesField(1,required=True),
                                              content_type=messages.StringField(2,required=True)),
              message_types.VoidMessage,
              name='upload.file',
              path='upload/file')
def upload_file(self, request):        
    create_file('bucket_name',request.file,request.content_type)
    return message_types.VoidMessage()
```

This works fine in development. However when I deploy to production and try uploading an image I get the following error:

Method: cloudStorageTest.upload.file
Error Code: 400
Reason: invalid
Message: Invalid bytes value: ...

I noticed that in production if I upload a very small text file it works but anything larger results in the above message. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get solution to this?